# How to use spaces within cron?

Tags: cron

While trying to run a cronjob (I don't have access to the SSH terminal, I only have access to record crons via a cPanel from my hosting) I need to put a space between the cron command itself:

```
wget -o https://abc.de/aaaaa/bbb ccc/ddd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

However, the cron job fails reporting:

```
wget: Unable to find directory https://abc.de/aaaaa/bbb
```

So how can I use a space there?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, URL encoding should do the trick:

```
https://abc.de/aaaaa/bbb%20ccc/ddd
```

but

```
wget -o "https://abc.de/aaaaa/bbb ccc/ddd"
```

should work as well.